# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and no extension method 'Skip' accepting a first argument of type 'object' - In Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

When trying to do some operation on array object i am getting the following error.

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and no extension
>   method 'Skip' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

cc and gg are list of items (List)

here is the code

```
@if (cc.Count > 6)
{
    gg = cc.Skip(6).ToList();
    cc = cc.Take(6).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is cc?? without the type it's hard to know the problem

Comment: What is the datatype of `cc` ? it is it object, you can not use `Skip` or `Take` method with it coz it does not have have it.

Comment: cc is a list of items

Comment: It sounds like the compile-time type of `cc` is just `object`. If it's meant to be a `List<T>` for some `T`, you should declare it that way. But generally we're not going to be able to help without more context. A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Does `cc.Count` work though? I would doubt it as `cc` is of type `object` so none of these methods should work.

Comment: yes its working and  it is also going into the loop. and breaking after that

Comment: Can you provide the controller method that creates the lists cc and gg please... and then the full view?

Comment: Are you using anonymous type to build `cc` list? Controller action method code to build the list is important to solve your issue, we expect you should include them into your question.

Answer (score 4):

Have you got a reference to System.Linq ?

```
using System.Linq;
```

Bit confused why cc.Count isn't throwing an error though...

Comment: The error says the variable is of type `object` so it doesn't matter what you import, it's not going to help.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down-voted. Take a closer look at the error message -  '(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Answer (score 0):

Please try rebuilding your project.

Comment: This is an answer, but maybe you want to rephrase to give it less of a comment impression.

Comment: Initially, I had tried leaving one but I'm hardly active enough to be allowed to do so.